# Hide Navigation Bar when soft keyboard is launched Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to hide the Navigation bar when the keyboard is launched from an edit text in a activity. i have tried a lot of solutions, but haven't had much luck.

The following code i found here in this forum, but it doesn't eliminate the nav bar when the keyboard is launched.

```
private void setupMainWindowDisplayMode()
{
    View decorView = setSystemUiVisilityMode();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
            new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    setSystemUiVisilityMode(); // Needed to avoid exiting immersive_sticky when keyboard is displayed
                }
            });
}

private View setSystemUiVisilityMode()
{
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int options;
    options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_LAYOUT_FLAGS;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(options);
    return decorView;
}
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well you may already know, but just to make it sure.

You can check if the  keyboard is visible or not with the following code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
    // keyboard is shown
} else {
    // keyboard is not shown
}
```

Then you can either hide or show the navigation bar.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html#40

On the above API, it says

```
With this approach, touching anywhere on the screen causes the navigation
bar (and status bar) to reappear and remain visible. The user
interaction causes the flags to be be cleared.
```

looks like this can be a problem. I wanted to check if this works, but I could get a device with softkey. Hope this helps.